# Can GPS device report to other device without internet?

Tags: gps, cloud-computing, tracking-devices

I have device A which that device made by only GPS+CONTROLLER.

Can that GPS report their location to device B which made by Controller or it will better report to internet without using GSM module or WiFi module? Is it possible?

If possible what device B contains and made? Or what device A should modify?

Comment: How far away would the two devices B? Of course if they’re within meters there are tons of ways to transmit data between them: BLE, WiFi are the most common but there are many others. If we’re talking hundreds or thousands of meters there are options like LoRa. Beyond that you’ll most certainly have to resort to going through the Internet, which often means going through a server for a number of reasons. Of course, in each case there are pros and cons for each tech: range, bandwidth, duty cycle, battery usage... you’ll have to tell us a lot more about what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I want DEVICE B recieved latitude and longitude (location) from DEVICE A for any distance.

Comment: If it’s from any distance, then yes, there’s no other option that going through the Internet and most likely a server. This means both devices must have a way to connect to the Internet: WiFi, Ethernet, cellular...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPS devices are receive only, they have no way to send any data to anywhere else unless you explicitly include the capability.

What you should use as back haul will entirely depend on how your device will be used. We don't have enough information in the question to make any assumptions.

Comment: I think the OP means something else by "GPS device" than you, but of course the question needs far more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways are there in GPS working, GPS will receive the information from safelight and locate you, one is AGPS , that will locate you very accurately and give you the data, this method for sure it needs Internet protocol to fetch the AGPS location itself, another method can locate you with satellite radio method ,  this method you can check in mobile when your data is off , satellite can locate you but initial fetching will take more time., so that now the ideology is it depends on the application, as you mentioned if you want to send the data continuously to the controller you need a protocol device like wifi or GSM on other hand locally you can use Bluetooth, on other hand your desire is only designing and tracing the geological location of the particular object in the sense you can do it without Internet and to make it effective you have to design it well